# X-Path outputting trailling zero

Tags: xpath, zero, trailing

The mission here is to output the final value in 5 decimal places, even if the decimals stop < 5 places, '0' is to be concatenated to it.

For example,

> x = '7.317' -> '7.31700';
>
> x = '8.14'  -> '8.14000';
>
> x = '1.2'   -> '1.20000';
>
> x = '1'     -> '1.00000';

I understand using `fn:format-number()` can resolve the matter, but is there an alternative to it?

I've tried the following,

`1) y = concat(x, "100000");`

`2) substring(y, string-length(x) + 1, 5);`

The result isn't promising though.

Checking through online, I notice some used `string-length(for $i ...)`, didn't quite understand this part.

Can the community please assist me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662151/padding-number-with-leading-zeros-in-xslt-1-0
https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/2083
https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/2083

The above are the few links that I've referred to and applied, but to no avail yet.

Comment: 1) Wouldn't you want `y = concat(x, "00000");`? And you should get the substring which ends five characters after the "." - or add a ".00000" if there isn't a "." in it. 2) This would probably be easier to do in the presentation layer.

Comment: @Vincent Please let me know if (and explain how) the linked dupe doesn't solve your problem.