# Get node position as attribute of a element

Tags: xslt

I want to Get node position as attribute of a element. I means I want to get `id` value like `Aut-01`,`Aut-02` inside `context` element. I mentioned below Input, output and tried code. I am using XSLT 2.0

Input :

```
       <con-group>
            <con c-type="aut">
                <name>
                    <fname>Kent-Dennis</fname>
                </name>
            </con>
            <con c-type="aut">
                <name>
                    <fname>dfr-gvfrt</fname>
                </name>
            </con>
            <con c-type="aut">
                <con-id con-id-type="ABC11"
                    >https://wasq.lk/0000-0002-8551-9535</con-id>
                <name>
                    <fname>Glazier</fname>
                </name>
            </con>
            <con c-type="aut">
                <con-id con-id-type="ABC12"
                    >https://wasq.lk/0000-0002-8551-8535</con-id>
                <name>
                    <fname>Glazier</fname>
                </name>
            </con>
      </con-group>
```

Output should be :

```
    <link ref="https://orcid.org/0000-0002-8551-9535">
        <context type="Aut" id="Aut-01">
            <image ref="../../../../command/Templates/Template Art/Auth_.jpg"/>
        </context><s/>
    <link>

    <link ref="https://orcid.org/0000-0002-8551-9535">
        <context type="Aut" id="Aut-02">
            <image ref="../../../../command/Templates/Template Art/Auth_.jpg"/>
        </context><s/>
    <link>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="con-id">
    <xsl:text>&#x2009;</xsl:text>
    <link ref="{.}">
        <xsl:variable name="aaa" select="count(self::con-id/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
        <context type="Aut" id="{$aaa}">
            <image ref="../../../../command/Templates/Template Art/Auth_.jpg"/>
        <context><s/>
    </link>
</xsl:template>
```

Help me to solve this. I am getting Id value always `1`. As my code I don't get output that I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding number with leading zeros in XSLT 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662151/padding-number-with-leading-zeros-in-xslt-1-0)

Comment: @ceving Actually I want to get the correct `Id` value. always I am getting `1` as my id value.

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="aaa" select="position()"/>`

Comment: And why do you calculate the position?

Comment: @MarcStröbel when i use `<xsl:variable name="aaa" select="position()"/>` I am getting `1` as `id` value always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting 1 each time because `con-id` has no preceding-siblings. (Elements are siblings if they have the same parent element). You should count preceding-siblings of the parent (but only if the preceding siblings have `con-id` it looks like)

```
<xsl:variable name="aaa" select="count(parent::*/preceding-sibling::*[con-id])+1"/>
```

Alternatively, you could use the `preceding` axis

```
<xsl:variable name="aaa" select="count(preceding::con-id)+1"/>
```

You could also use `xsl:number` here

```
<xsl:variable name="aaa">
    <xsl:number count="con[con-id]" />
</xsl:variable>
```

If you want to use `position()` you would have to add another template to match `con-group` and then only select `con-id` elements (although this would only really work if you didn't have other processing you wanted to do that might clash).

```
<xsl:template match="con-group">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/con-id" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="con-id">
    <xsl:text>&#x2009;</xsl:text>
    <link ref="{.}">
        <xsl:variable name="aaa" select="position()" />
        <context type="Aut" id="{$aaa}">
            <image ref="../../../../command/Templates/Template Art/Auth_.jpg"/>
        </context><s/>
    </link>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:-

```
<xsl:template match="con">
    <xsl:variable name="aaa" select="position()"/>
<xsl:for-each select="con-id">
    <xsl:text>&#x2009;</xsl:text>
    <link ref="{.}">
        <context type="Aut" id="{$aaa}">
            <image ref="../../../../command/Templates/Template Art/Auth_.jpg"/>
        </context>
    </link>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Still I am always getting `1` as `id` value

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//con-id">
<link ref="{.}">
        <xsl:variable name="aaa" select="position()"/>
        <context type="Aut" id="{$aaa}">
            <image ref="../../../../command/Templates/Template Art/Auth_.jpg"/>
        </context>
    </link>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This Also not working. I want to do this without using `xsl:for-each`