# Need to retain leading zeros while generating XML from Excel

Tags: excel, xml, types, leading-zero

I have an Excel sheet. In that sheet, one of the column ( name as ID) has values with leading zeros. For example-
**ID -- 000987654321**

When I am generating XML from Excel, the leading zeros are getting dropped.

While generating XML, I tried to map it like -- 
`<xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:decimal" />`

Need help with what datatype should I put so that the leading zeros do not get dropped while generating XML.

Comment: If you want to use a numeric type like `decimal` then it doesn't make sense to preserve the leading zeroes. Either use a string type, or lose the zeroes and re-add them when displaying the value.

Comment: @jsheeran string datatype also i tried, it is also not reserving leading zeros

Comment: In Excel, are the zeroes part of the value or added by cell formatting?

Comment: I added by cell formatting, example -- values are ranging from 8 to 12 digits. However, I need 12 digits number, so I am appending the zeros by customzing cell formatting. I typed 000000000000 in the custom part of the cell format in Home Tab. Hence all the values become 12 digits. example - 87654321 will come  000087654321 , 987654321 becomes 000987654321 , 123456789123 remains 123456789123

Comment: You'll need to apply the same transformation to your XML as you are in the cell formatting. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662151/padding-number-with-leading-zeros-in-xslt-1-0) may be of relevance.

Comment: @jsheeran not really.. since my excel is now having correct values as expected, now i need to generate xml and i would need help with xml supported datatype for leading zeros

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205667/discussion-between-sneha-and-jsheeran).